# Magento 2.4 Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2.4

As of Magento 2.4.0, Elasticsearch 7.6.x is required for all installations. Our shared hosting provider doesn't support Elasticsearch.

What can we do to update to Magento 2.4.0 while keeping the search function working correctly?

We're looking for a free solution.

Comment: Did you manage to come right? I have the same issue and there is no documentation on how to use a hosted ElasticSearch Service together with Magento 2.4. Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting does not support ElasticSearch you will need to consider moving to a new dedicated host where you can install a free Elastic Search server yourself or use an external service such as Amazons Elasticsearch Service.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/

I think you will struggle to find a free external service that you can rely on for Magento catalog search.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move your entire website to a new host, you just need an external Elastic Search service. You can configure the hostname and port of ES from the Magento admin area.